# Carousel doesn't show up in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, carousel, microsoft-edge

We have this carousel to show recent blog posts on our homepage: http://www.idea-kraft.com/

It uses the WP Posts Carousel plugin at plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-posts-carousel.

Nothing shows up in MS Edge:
[Screenshot of missing carousel in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA9MZ.jpg)

The plugin uses OWL Carousel 2.

I may just build from scratch, but juggling priorities right now it would be great if anyone knows a fix. Any ideas welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Bump to notify I've attached a screenshot and added a reference link to the plugin code, so hopefully that helps. MS Edge appears to be incompatible with most carousel slider WordPress plugins.

Comment: It works fine in IE11 and in Edge. The only problem in Edge is the fading.

Comment: @Grasper Thanks. We're testing in Edge 15 on Windows 10, as well as Edge 14 and 15 in BrowserStack. Checked settings, cleared cache and still blank for us…

(JS is enabled)

Comment: Edge 25 and win10 works fine

Comment: Has this been verified as an issue with Owl (I can't find a Github ticket about it)? I'm having issues with Owl Carousel 2 loading in Edge, but am unsure whether it's Owl Carousel or something else in our stack.